# Viewmodel bindings are called multiply (first on load view, second and switching to other view)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

i have little problem with binding from View to Vievmodel.

i have menu. This menu have 5-6 items. Every menu item have own usercontent.

```
1st - home.xaml
2nd - informations.xaml
3rd - more.xalm etc...
```

if i click on informations (2nd menu), this usercontrol view will be displayed, abd all elements like name,adress,phone,email etc are binding to viewmodel and data are loaded (by SQL select inside get).
This is all OK

BUT

if i click to 3rd menu, 2nd menu disapears, 3rd menu are displayd, and in this time i see in console, all sql are called again !

code here :

viewmodel.cs

```
    public string BIND_USERNAME {
    get { return SQL_READDATA("SYBASE", "select A.SKUPAKCE1 from AKCE_V A where A._ID='" + BIND_INTERNIIDAKCE + "'", "console"); }'
    }


informations.xaml
```

````
<Label  Content="{binding BIND_USERNAME}"  Style="{StaticResource sekceheader}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />```
````

Complete code is here : https://github.com/sgamescz/HH6C

I have now whole program slow, because of every view are (via binding) filled twice :(

Comment: You've not described what you are doing in your code in enough detail. I guess you click a menu button and you're navigating. The way I'd suggest doing this is to use viewmodel first navigation and cache the viewmodels in a dictionary as you do so. That way when they navigate to one you already showed, the viewmodel with the data in it is in your dictionary and you can avoid going back to the database.

Comment: Looks like the third view instantiates a new view model instance instead of reusing the previous instance. But there are not enough details. Please post the relevant code. Reduce it to a minimal example that reproduces the behavior you are observing.

Comment: Also you shouldn't hide a database query inside a properties' get method. It should be a method, that is explicitly called when the caller deliberately wants to query the data. A property is expected to be lightweight, storing simple values and should not trigger expensive or long running operations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a query in a property `get`.

When you switch to a new XAML file, that file needs to read the property, and the query is run again.

You could move the query to the object constructor, and store the value in the property.

```
public class viewmodel
{
    public viewmodel()
    {
        this.BIND_USERNAME = SQL_READDATA(...
    }

    public string BIND_USERNAME { get; }
}
```

This should query for the value once, and reuse that value every time the property is called.

Comment: View model shouldn't dispatch SQL queries. This should be part of the model.